# Global variable doesn't accept change in python

Tags: python

I created a small program to select a file and then display the filepath using print OUTSIDE the openfile function (I need to access the file_path variable outside because I plan on using it for other stuff). I declared it as a global variable but the output is still empty. When I use print(file_path) inside the openfile function it works perfectly. I'm new to programming so bear with. TYIW

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pyperclip

file_path = ''

def OpenFile():
    global file_path
    file_path = fd.askopenfilename()


print(file_path)
#GUI
window = Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')



Open_button = Button(window,text='Select File', command=OpenFile)
Open_button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you define OpenFile but you don't call it.

Comment: `OpenFile` gets called, but it gets called *after* the `print` statement.

Comment: Your print statement is after your call to `OpenFile`, put the print statement at the end of the file and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: The `OpenFile` call (possible many of them) happen inside `mainloop()`.  If you put the print statement before `mainloop` it will happen before any buttons have clicked; if you put it afterward it will happen right before the app exits.  Whatever you want to do with `file_path` needs to be driven by other GUI events.  (Also, you should use Tk's mutable variables instead of `global`!)

Comment: I tried using a label to print the value of the path and that too doesn't seem to work ( label = Label(window, fg='black', text=file_path, compound='left')
label.pack() )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is an interpreter based language, So it read's the code line by line.

```
file_path = '' # First reads this
 
def OpenFile(): # then reads this function
    global file_path
    file_path = fd.askopenfilename()


print(file_path) # then this
```

The functions wont execute until you call it. You may have noticed that before printing `file_path` you havnt called `OpenFile` function, so the variable `file_path`s value is ''.

I would to set focus on `window.mainloop()` function. `mainloop` is an important part of tkinter application as it tells Python to run Tkinter's Event loop. This method listens for events, such as button clicks or keypresses, and blocks any code that comes after it from running until you close the window where you called the method.

For more details of `mainloop` see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/16187613).

The `mainloop` checks if any event is been passed, if passed then only updates the tkinter window. `mainloop` is actually a loop of `update()` and `update_idletask()` so it would only execute `print(file_path)` once unless and untill you have called it multiple times or in another loop.

So there are 3 solution for your problem:

1. Adding another button and printing through it.

```
def printing():
    print(file_path)

print_button = Button(window,text='Click to print value:', command=printing)
print_button.pack()
```

2. Using text variables:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import pyperclip

file_path = StringVar()

def OpenFile():
    global file_path
    file_path.set(fd.askopenfilename()) ###

window = Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')



Open_button = Button(window,text='Select File', command=OpenFile)
Open_button.pack()
a=Label(window,textvariable=file_path)
a.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

3. Using `.config`:

```
def OpenFile():
    global file_path
    file_path = fd.askopenfilename()
    a.config(text=file_path)
```

Comment: Languages are neither compiled nor interpreted; *implementations* choose one of the other to implement the language. CPython *compiles* Python source code to a byte code which is then executed by a virtual machine. Neither approach explains why `OpenFile` is not called immediately after it is *defined*.

Comment: @chepner , I am not able to get you, the official site of python states *"Python is an interpreted, object-oriented, high-level programming language with dynamic semantics."*.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function after you print the value, so it has not yet changed when you print.

Try to print the value after the function is called.

Comment: writing the statement after openfile button command doesn't work either and placing it at the end only prints the path after I close the gui window.

Comment: Since you are using GUI events, you will have to access the path via like a "Submit" button. Check out information about [the event loop](https://python-course.eu/tkinter/events-and-binds-in-tkinter.php)